# Ruby script for matching 3 patterns on ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a **fail2ban.log** from which I want to grab specific fields, from 'Ban' strings. I can grab the data I need using **regex** one at the time, but I am not able to combine them. A typical 'fail2ban' log file has many strings. I'm interested in strings like these:

```
2012-05-02 14:47:40,515 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh-iptables] Ban 84.xx.xx.242
```

xx = numbers (digits)

I want to grab: a) Date and Time, b) Ban (keyword), c) IP address

Here is my regex:

IP = `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})`

date & time = `^(\d{4}\W\d{2}\W\d{2}\s\d{2}\W\d{2}\W\d{2})`

My problem here is, how can I combine these three together. I tried something like this:

```
^(?=^\d{4}\W\d{2}\W\d{2}\s\d{2}\W\d{2}\W\d{2})(?=\.*d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$)(?=^(?Ban).)*$).*$
```

but does not work as I would wanted too.

To give a clearer example, here is what I want:

```
greyjewel:FailMap atma$ cat fail2ban.log |grep Ban|awk -F " " '{print $1, $2, $7}'|tail -n 3
2012-05-02 14:47:40,515 84.51.18.242
2012-05-03 00:35:44,520 202.164.46.29
2012-05-03 17:55:03,725 203.92.42.6
```

Best Regards

Comment: In general,`grep foo | awk '{bar}'` is better written as just `awk '/foo/ {bar}'`, no grep required.

Comment: could you please provide a full featured example, on this will work using awk only? My file in this case is called 'fail2ban.log' and I want to grab all the lines that have the word 'Ban' and then print the $1, $2 and $7 field. Thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: `awk '/Ban/ {print $1, $2, $(NF-1), $NF}' fail2ban.log`

or, to avoid false positives, `awk '$(NF-1)=="Ban" {print $1, $2, $(NF-1), $NF}' fail2ban.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty direct translation of the example

```
ruby -alne 'BEGIN {$,=" "}; print $F.values_at(0,1,-1) if /Ban/' fail2ban.log
```

And because I figure you must want them from within Ruby

```
results = File.foreach("input").grep(/Ban/).map { |line| line.chomp.split.values_at 0, 1, -1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the field placement doesn't change, you don't even need a regex here:

```
log_line = 
  '2012-05-02 14:47:40,515 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh-iptables] Ban 84.12.34.242'

date, time, action, ip = log_line.split.values_at(0,1,-2,-1)
```